# send data from separate thread to main thread in background android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

In my application, I want to send the data from background thread to main thread but do not want to exit from that thread.

Shared Preference and Database is solving my problem any alternate way to resolve this like Bundle or Intent.

I think Bundle or Intent will start the activity. Please correct me If I am wrong.

Thanks

Comment: you should use `Handler`, that's all

Comment: @pskink to parse the data?

Comment: no, use it to "send data from separate thread to main thread", it is your main question, isn it?

Comment: @pskink please have a look to description, I want the way to send data

Comment: use `Handler` then, see `Handler#obtainMessage` and any of `Handler#send*` method